# Read HTTPS URL's in R like linkedin

Tags: python, r, https, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to read the LinkedIn company page, for example, https://www.linkedin.com/company/facebook

getting company name,location,type of industry,etc.

This is my code below

```
urlCreate1<-"https://www.linkedin.com/company/facebook"
parse_rvest<-getURL(urlCreate1,'useragent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36") 
nameRest <- content %>%html_nodes(".industry") %>%html_text()
nameRest
```

and the output I get for this is character(0) which from previous posts I understand that its not getting `.industry` tag as I read the https code.

I have also tried this

```
parse_rvest<-content(GET(urlCreate1),encoding='UTF-8')
```

but it doesn't help

I have a python code that works but I need this to be done in R

This is part of the python code I got online

```
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            formatted_response = response.content.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
            doc = html.fromstring(formatted_response)
            datafrom_xpath = doc.xpath('//code[@id="stream-promo-top-bar-embed-id-content"]//text()')
            if datafrom_xpath:
                try:
                    json_formatted_data = json.loads(datafrom_xpath[0])
                    company_name = json_formatted_data['companyName'] if 'companyName' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                    size = json_formatted_data['size'] if 'size' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
```

Please help me in reading the page. I am using selector gadget to get the xpath(.industry)

Comment: Best bet would be to go through API way. LinkedIn provides API which I have not investigated a lot. Please do the right way of extracting data from websites like LinkedIn

Comment: @Bharath best way in the sense??legal way? with python it works...I jst want to know how to read the full page...coz for some reason only the head gets read

Comment: LinkedIn actually sued scrapers in 2016. This is unwise activity. Please don't drag R ppl into your ethical and legal pending nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the LIN API:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rlinkedin/Rlinkedin.pdf

Then, you should be able to easily, and legally, do whatever you want to do.

Here are some ideas to get you started.

http://thinktostart.com/analyze-linkedin-with-r/

https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/200

https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/3rufk5/pulling_data_from_linkedin_api/